# Get data from WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I'm so confused. Although I have a fair background in C#, this is my first exposure to WCF.

I have a C# desktop application that does a few functions such as getting data from a local xml file, and other various functions, which I don't need to explain here because they don't relate to this question. Now I need to use a URL for a WCF Service to get some other data to use in my application.

The more I read about WCF online and go through the tutorials the more confused I get. That's why I'm requesting a really simple, clear, straight-forward answer to my questions here. I'm not looking for anything fancy or advanced like setting up a WCF Service Library or WCF Service Application. I'm simply a beginner to WCF who wants to use a WCF service URL in my existing C# desktop application to get some data. The WCF service was provided to me by someone else, and is properly working. Please keep in mind when answering this question that I am new to WCF, so a beginner level answer to this topic is best.

This is what I've don so far:

1. Created a C# Windows Forms Application that properly builds and runs. The application has a few custom classes, a local xml file for data retrieval, and some event handlers for button clicks and such in the Form1 class.
2. I added the WCF service reference to my project (i.e., right-click project > Add Service Reference > paste in url > Go > Ok.
3. Added the `System.Data.Services.Client` reference to my project. Although I don't know if this is even needed.
4. In my Form1 class where the event handlers are, I added the following using directives: `using MyProject.theService` and `using System.Data.Services.Client`.
5. Added these global variables at the beginning of the Form1 class:

   `private Uri svcUri = new Uri("http://www ... service.svc");

    private ServiceClient context;`
6. In the Form1 class, in a button event, I have the following code:

-

```
private void btnWebService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

    Student s = new Student();

    // this is implemented as follows in the student class: public Fee[] Fees { get; set; }
    Fee f = new Fee();   

    // need some logic here to get the data using the client object

    client.Close();
}
```

There is a method of the client object called GetFees (`client.GetFees()`) and I'm assuming it is the most logical choice to use this method to get the data I need (which is the fees associated with the students). Visual Studio gives this description of the method:

`theService.Student[] ServiceClient.GetFees(theService.Student[] students)`

What I'd like is when I click the button and fire the btnWebService_Click event, I call the service, retrieve the needed data, store it in the appropriate object, and have the data to use however I need.

My question are:

- On step 6, am I moving the right direction?
- Have I missed any steps in order to made the WCF call work?
- The GetFees() method is confusing me. How do I write the correct C# code to use it without errors?

I've tried writing this line of code in the event handler:

```
f = client.GetFees(s.Fees[0]);
```

But I get the following errors in Visual Studio:

- The best overloaded method match for 'MyProject.theService.ServiceClient.GetFees(MyProject.theService.Student[])' has some invalid arguments
- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MyProject.Fee' to 'MyProject.theService.Student[]'

What is am I doing wrong here? Or is this line even close to anything I need?

I've purposefully excluded the full url of the WCF service from this question. If it helps to have it to properly answer this question please let me know and I will give it to you. Also, there is a wsdl url. Let me know if having it will help you answer my questions.

Thank you in advance for reading all this. I welcome and appreciate any kind of help you can provide.

**------------------------- EDIT -------------------------**

Based on some of the help I've received I'm getting very close to a solution. But I still have one issue.

This code compiles and runs:

```
private void btnWebService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

    theService.Student s = new theService.Student();

    theService.Student[] stds = new theService.Student[30];
    stds[0] = s;  

    var ret = client.GetFees(stds);  

    client.Close();
}
```

**However**, I get the following error from Visual Studio:

- Invalid StudentID(=0). StudentID must be greater than 0.

This error occurs because the values in `stds[0]` are null.

In a different part of my program, I have a LINQ query that grabs the student data from an xml file and stores it in a `List<Student> students` object.

So looking at the code above, my next step would be to assign the values from `students` to `stds[0]`. The **problem I cannot figure out** is some issue with casting or conversion. **How do I assign student objects from List to a theService.Student[] object** so that I can provide the service some data to look up?

I've tried doing this:

```
stds[0] = (theService.Student)students[0];
```

But of course I get this error:

- Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyProject.Student' to 'MyProject.theService.Student'

I know this might seem really simple and obvious to some, but I cannot figure it out. I can't find the answer on Google. Someone please help.

Comment: What is the purpose of WCF in your application ?? WCF as far as I know it, is Windows Communication Foundation. meaning you use it in order to communicate between 2 processes, running both locally or one locally and one remote.

Comment: The WCF enables me to "get fees associated with the students". In other words, I can use it to grab some data from a remote source. I've been provided with the WCF url, and now I need to use it in my application to get the data. Making the connection and getting the data is the confusing part. Once I get the data I can do whatever I want with it. For example, I could display the data in a listbox if I wanted to. So, the purpose of the WCF in my application is to get some data. Does that help?

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward:  You are sending `MyProject.Fee` when you should be sending `MyProject.theService.Student[]`.

Comment: @zimdanen, yes that seems to be the issue. I know how to create an array of student objects(`Student[] stds = new Student[30];`), but how do I create an array of MyProject.theService.Student[]??

Comment: Please see the new part I've added above to my question, after Edit. It explains the issue more clearly. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your local information stored in an object called `Student`, and the service expects an object called `Student` but they are not the same thing.

I recommend creating either:

- a) creating an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) on YOUR student object to convert it to a service student object
- b) creating an [explicit conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) for your student object into a the service student object

but, the long way will be to do something like:

```
theService.Student s = new theService.Student();
s.Name = students[0].Name; //these are example fields
s.Id = students[0].Id;     //these are example fields

var ret = client.GetFees(new theService.Student[] { s });
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I wasn't too sure about the options a and b, but the code you gave is straight forward and works.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, you're just not calling the service as expected. The service expects you to pass in an array of Student objects, and it will return an array of Student objects.

```
theService.Student[] ServiceClient.GetFees(theService.Student[] students)
```

Try something like

```
var stds = new Student[];
stds[0] = s;  // the Student you set up

var ret = client.GetFees( stds );  // ret is an array of Student
f = ret[0];  since you only passed a single student in, the 1st item in the return array should be your student with fees
```

Now, look at f.Fees for your data.

You can shorten this code quite a bit; I wanted to show discrete steps.

Comment: You need to give the array a size or it will blow up when you try to assign at index 0.

Comment: @Val, thank you for this help. I've modified a part of the code to fix a syntax error. Although this helps me a lot, I still get an error on this line: `var ret = client.GetFees(stds);`

Comment: The errors are: `The best overloaded method match for 'MyProject.theService.ServiceClient.GetFees(MyProject.theService.Student[])' has some invalid arguments`

and
`cannot convert from 'MyProject.Student[]' to 'MyProject.theService.Student[]'`

Comment: Do I need to cast something??

Comment: @Zolt:  Use `theService.Student[]` instead of `Student[]`, or map from your `Student` class to the contract class.

Comment: @Val or anyone, please see the new edited part I've added above to my question. It explains the issue now more clearly. Please help.